# Firestore Transaction Semantics With Read Queries

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

In the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) it is stated, that a transaction fails, when:

> The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction.

I'm wondering if this also applies to read queries, that might return more than one document (via `.where('x', '==', 'y')`). Does the transaction still fail, if the Read query would return more results if it was executed again sometime during the transaction?

To illustrate my question, let's say I have a collection of cars with the following Schema:

```
{ 
   ownerId: string, 
   make: string,
   horsepower: int
   ...
}
```

Now I'm querying the cars of a certain owner in a `transaction.get()` call:

```
transaction.get(firestore.collection('cars').where('ownerId', '==', '123'))...
```

Let's say I receive a `Snapshot` with 2 Cars, based on these cars I want to do some magic in the transaction. During the transaction another car is **added** for this owner (so it's not part of the initial Snapshot). Will the transaction fail in this case?

PS: I'm not looking for a different solution, the example above is fictitious, I just want to understand how the transaction behaves in this kind of case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say I receive a Snapshot with 2 Cars, based on these cars I want to do some magic in the transaction. During the transaction another car is added for this owner (so it's not part of the initial Snapshot). Will the transaction fail in this case?

Definitely no. Since the new added car is not apart of the initial transaction, it won't fail. The car that is added is consider a new added object and not an object that was modified.

They mention in the docs that:

> The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction.

Because a transaction absolutely requires round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully. So that's why a transaction will fail if that particular document is modified by an operation other than the transaction in which is already involved.

Comment: Adding on that, it bothers me a lot during my day to day tasks when I encounter use cases where, to write 100% reliable business logic, it is required that the transaction should either _retry itself_ or _rejects any incoming writes_ to the database which can possible change the scope of the query.

Are there any best practices or perfectly reliable solutions to address those scenarios.

Comment: @MohammedMaaz It's best to post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.